# How to select cascading DropDownList with MS SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
IDVehicle Make        Model
   0       BMW      5 series
   1       BMW      4 series
   2       AUDI        A4
   3       AUDI        A6
   4       TOYOTA      vios
   5       TOYOTA      RAV4
```

In the c# designer view, I have 2 drop-down list one which has Make and other for Model.

What I want is that when user picks 'BMW' in Make list, the Model list should have the following `5 series, 4 series`

**ASPX.CS**

```
Make: <asp:DropDownList ID="<MakeList" runat="server" /><br/>
Model: <asp:DropDownList ID="ModelList" runat="server"/><br />
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccd1" runat="server"
    ServicePath="CascadingDropdown1.cs.asmx"
    ServiceMethod="GetMake"
    TargetControlID="MakeList" Category="Make"
    PromptText="Select Make"/>

<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccd2" runat="server"
    ServicePath="CascadingDropdown1.cs.asmx"
    ServiceMethod="GetModelForMake"
    TargetControlID="ModelList" ParentControlID="MakeList"
    Category="Model"
    PromptText="Select Model"/>
```

my problem is that I'm so confused about the query and the column name will be used in the `.cs.asmx` file.

**EDIT**

Am i Doing wrong in here ?

```
[WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetMakes(string knownCategoryValues)
    {
        string query = "SELECT VehicleMake, VehicleMakeId FROM Makes";
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> Makes = GetData(query);
        return Makes.ToArray();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetModels(string knownCategoryValues)
    {
        string make = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)["MakeId"];
        string query = string.Format("SELECT VehicleModel, VehicleModelId FROM Models WHERE MakeId = {0}", make);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> Models = GetData(query);
        return Models.ToArray();
    }

    private List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVER=xbetasql,52292;UID=AutoTrakker;Password=trinidad2win;DATABASE=ATDBSQL;"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue
                    {
                        name = reader[0].ToString(),
                        value = reader[1].ToString()
                    });
                }
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();
                return values;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am having an error. it says `[Method Error 500]`

**UPDATE**

Is it ok not to have an ID for each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMake" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlMake" TargetControlID="ddlMake" PromptText="Select Make" PromptValue="" ServicePath="CascadingDropdown1.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetMakes" runat="server" Category="VehicleMakeId" LoadingText="Loading Make..." />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModel" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlModel" TargetControlID="ddlModel" PromptText="Select Model" PromptValue="" ServicePath="CascadingDropdown1.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetModels" runat="server" Category="VehicleModelId" ParentControlID="ddlMake" LoadingText="Loading Model..." />
```

**CascadingDropDown Properties**

Below are some important properties of the AJAX CascadingDropDown

- TargetControlID – Here we need to set the ID of the DropDownList control for which you want to make an AJAX Cascading DropDownList.
- ServicePath – Here we set the URL of the Web Service that will act as source of data for the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList.
- ServiceMethod – Here we set the name of the Web Method that will be used to populate the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList.
- PromptText – This property is the Text part that of the first or the default item that will be displayed in the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList.
- PromptValue – This property is the Value part that of the first or the default item that will be displayed in the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList.
- Category – This property is used to specify the Category for the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList, Category value is passed as parameter to the Child or dependent AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList ServiceMethod i.e. Web Method.
- ParentControlID – This property is used to set the ID of the DropDownList on whose selection the DropDownList will trigger the data population process.
- LoadingText– This property used to display the loading text when the call is made to the Web Method until the data is populated in the AJAX CascadingDropDown DropDownList.

And have your `WebMethods` as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetMakes(string knownCategoryValues)
{
    string query = "SELECT VehicleMakeName, VehicleMakeId FROM Makes";
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> Makes = GetData(query);
    return Makes.ToArray();
}

[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetModels(string knownCategoryValues)
{
    string make = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)["MakeId"];
    string query = string.Format("SELECT VehicleModelName, VehicleModelId FROM Models WHERE MakeId = {0}", make);
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> Models = GetData(query);
    return Models.ToArray();
}

private List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> GetData(string query)
{
   string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue
                {
                    name = reader[0].ToString(),
                    value = reader[1].ToString()
                });
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i put in the `cs.asmx` file sir?

Comment: sorry sir but I'm really confused about the query sir? can you help me with the `SELECT` thing sir? By the way here are the column name `VehicleMake, VehicleModel` @ANewGuyInTown

Comment: see my edited answer, just change column names in the `select` to whichever you want to `display` (as the first column as name of your model/make) and the `identifier` as the second column (which is `id` (e.g. `makeId` that you passing to filter the Model `dropdownlist`)

Comment: I'm having an error sir. It says in the `select` `[Method Error 500]` @ANewGuyInTown

Comment: did you change your `ServiceMethod="GetMakes"` and ServiceMethod="GetModels" ? I think I edited my answer to correct the `method names` in the `dropdownlists`

Comment: i just changed it now. how about the `query` sir? how to right the correct `query` for this? @ANewGuyInTown

Comment: When i run the program it will break in the `string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;` @ANewGuyInTown

Comment: check your `web.config` file, you should have/create an entry for connection string with name `ConnectionStr`. Otherwise try supplying the connection string directly and see what happens. Follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411(v=vs.140).aspx) for more details on how to read from connection string.

Comment: sir I have a stored procedure for make and model. can you show me how to apply it in the code? ty @ANewGuyInTown